# Symfony2 change twig lexer

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I want to change default twig lexer in symfony2.

- I created custom controller
- setup service for it
- set up routes to service
- inject twig lexer to service
- change lexer in constructor of my controller
- result is rendered fine when I don't use interpolation
- but lexer doesn't change still {{ }} is parsed by twig

.

```
class MyController
{
 private $twig;

 public function __construct( Environment $twig)
 {
    $this->twig = $twig;
    $lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
        'tag_comment'   => array('[#', '#]'),
        'tag_block'     => array('[%', '%]'),
        'tag_variable'  => array('[[', ']]'),
        'interpolation' => array('#[', ']'),
    ));
    $this->twig->setLexer($lexer);
 }

 public function indexAction()
 {
    return new Response($this->twig->render(
        '@Template/index.html.twig'
    ));
 }
}
```

there is variable with {{ alert }} interpolation for angularjs and response from symfony is

```
Variable "alert" does not exist in @Template/index.html.twig at line 3
```

so lexer doesn't change

Comment: Not what you ask, but related: there's `verbatim` twig tag which helps a lot with JS templating. Also, this way you do not loose IDE's/plugins support for twig files.

Comment: verbatim is working but my use of twig is really low, there would be  verbatim everywhere. For me would be better opposite, specify where in document twig should parse content.

Comment: We have same for serving ng partial templates, thus every twig template has `verbatim` as root element and that's it for twig there.

Comment: That works. I have it like this in other projects. But I was just curious.

Now I found that it was probably some magic cache (even if I'm using app_dev) because solution above works fine.