# Twig output after rendering is html + twig code

Tags: php, twig

I am using twig and output is rendered like without any processing.

Example:

```
ABCDE

{% if test is defined %}
    defined!
{% endif %}
```

I wrote the following code:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem( __DIR__ . '/src/Gui/views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache'=>false));
$template = $twig->load('test.html');
echo $template->render([]);
```

Template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>ABCDE</p>
        {% if test is defined %}
            <p>defined!</p>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I used different templates, but the result does not change.

Comment: Your example works correctly with twig 2.5.0 on PHP 7.2.2. Please check if you have any errors in php error.log.

Comment: Try with `$twig->render('test.html' , []);` instead

Comment: @joshas, log file is empty (in php.ini this options is activated). PHP version 7.1.9, twig - 2.5

Comment: @DarkBee, the result is same..

Comment: Try reinstalling  the `twig` lib?

Comment: @DarkBee, yes, nothing change

Comment: Try enabling the `debug`-mode i'd say `$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());`

Comment: @DarkBee, I activate it and was trying to use something like {{ dump(test) }} but it doesn't work. 
I have made some test in twig lib files, and noticed that method tokenize inside Lexer.php don't recoginze any occurrence of special sequences. So {%, {{ is ignored. And result of preg_match_all() is empty array.

Comment: Perhaps something has changed the lexer in your project. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298673/symfony2-change-twig-lexer) how to configure the lexer back to default

Comment: Perhaps the problem is different .. Sorry, I moved away from the original question. I tried it now: preg_match_all('/(dog)/', 'dog cat dog', $matches); And it gives a result of empty array. PCRE is enabled. So this question must be closed.

Comment: @DarkBee, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Martin no problem - you got me a little confused here though! ^^