# twig show all content raw like {{#equals language "en"}}

Tags: symfony, twig

We're working on twig to merge multiple values. The idea is to have multiple twig templates each containing the value of it's language.

The problem is the values contain handlebars conditions like `{{#equals language "nl_NL"}}` that causes trouble in twig.

Is it possible to show all contents raw?

Comment: Did you check out the [i18n](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) extension?

Comment: Hi DarkBee, I know about the extension. But it's not supposed to detect the language. I want the {{#equals language "nl_NL"}} to render as raw content.

Comment: You could change [twig's lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298673/symfony2-change-twig-lexer)?